# Why does this code works? Calling executeQuery without Load [CSOM]

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, csom, query

First question:
Why we don't need ctx.Load(web) before defining the List? I see that we use web object in defining the List

Second question:
Why are we not calling ctx.Load() before ExecuteQuery method?

[image: Picture CSOM approach]

Answer (score 0):

I’m no cso expert, but i think load just forces the objects to be downloaded to the client so you can reference them there. You are not referencing those objects on the client.